# Query Working Fine MS SQL but Giving Error in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

```
select count(ratings) as number_of_ratings,sum(ratings) as sum_of_ratings 
from performance_reviews 
where year(review_date)=2004 and employee_id='00009-1761417-9';
```

i am executing above QUERY in php it is giving error

> incorrect syntax near '2004'

i also tried it with

```
select count(ratings) as number_of_ratings,sum(ratings) as sum_of_ratings 
from performance_reviews 
where year(review_date)='2004' and employee_id='00009-1761417-9';
```

my php query as

```
$query = "select count(ratings) as number_of_ratings,sum(ratings) as sum_of_ratings 
          from performance_reviews 
          where year(review_date)='$year' and employee_id='$emp_id'";
```

Whats Error in it

Comment: Same error with both executions?

Comment: no when i execute query in ms sql then i got no error and get desired output while when i try to execute through php it gives me error

Comment: You said `i also tried`, so there were two attempts in PHP though, right? Both gave the same behavior?

Comment: Yes both giving same behaviour

Comment: Was the first execution with variable, or static value? e.g. `$query = "select count(ratings) as number_of_ratings,sum(ratings) as sum_of_ratings 
          from performance_reviews 
          where year(review_date)=2004 and employee_id='$emp_id'";` is the same?

Comment: can you print $query with the values being set?, by the way you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Your first query that runs successfully doesn't contain single quotes around the year, but for whatever reason you have added them in your PHP version. Furthermore, [you should be binding your parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php), not concatenating them. Lastly, you are trying to concatenate parameters inside single quotes which probably isn't going to work. Print out $query to the screen after that variable is set and see the SQL you are generating. Try to run that sql you generated in a client. Does it work or does it throw the same error?

Comment: @JNevill i tried everything now moved to procedures but its same error incorrect syntax near 2004(or any value)

Comment: Ultimately though I think you should work on binding your parameters. Right now you are leaving yourself open to sql injection. Fixing the issue you are facing now is sort of a waste since it will need to be rewritten as a prepared statement to avoid a sql injection attack.

Comment: What is "Everything" that you tried? Did you remove those superfluous single quotes around the year? Did you inspect the value of $query to show the sql being generated before php sends it to the database? If so, can you share that sql statement here?

Comment: @JNevill thanks man i followed the prepared statement and it worked everything resolved

Comment: @OsamaInayat That is great news! You'll have much more secure code and, oddly, even though it's more lines of code, it's easier to write and maintain. I'm super glad you got it working :)